# Change TiledTextureRegion of Animated Sprite in Andengine

Tags: android, andengine

The title is self explanatory. How to change from a previously defined sprite.

Comment: Maybe this will help you? :http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/changing-textureregion-dinamically-on-sprite-t4352.html

Comment: Just create a new animatedSprite with new Texture and assign that you your current sprite.. Will it not do the job?

Comment: @laymelek That was my original idea,but the sprite act weird the first 2 or 3 times it runs there(the image doesnt fit the sprite and dont animate properly) and just later acts ok. Obviouslyi want it to run ok since the first time so i thought it was not the proper way

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka i added it to the Sprite.java and it worked! Im sorry i wasted both of yur time.

Comment: Post your code as an answer for others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this extra method to Sprite class and it fix the issue

```
  public void setTextureRegion(ITextureRegion textureRegion) {
    this.mTextureRegion = textureRegion;
    this.setSize(this.mTextureRegion.getWidth(), this.mTextureRegion.getHeight());
    onUpdateVertices();
    onUpdateTextureCoordinates();
}
```

**NOTE:** You have to delete final from mTextureRegion. And you need the other 3 lines or else it will act strange. Im not sure why.